# How To - Unlist my program from the process list..?

Tags: c#, winforms, security, process

Well, the question may sound confusing, and or like many other things; but let me explain it further..

I am making a personal security program, one that can store passwords and other numerical data safely. I'm taking somewhat of a **"Right in-front of your face"** approach with it..

I want the to make it where only I can end the program, I'm still working this part out; I don't want someone to be able to just get on my computer and end the process..

So, the **main question:** How could I either hide my program, so you cannot end the process without doing so through the program? Or, just make it where you can't end the process, without hiding it..

I guess one other question would be: Is this even achievable? Or am I just thinking like a mad man? Which I very well could be..

Comment: are you aware of http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to hide a process in Windows.  You can, however, write a *pair* of processes watching over each other, and each restarts its partner when it detects that the partner has disappeared.  Incidentally, quite a few **viruses** work this way.

Comment: @Stephen: Yeah, I bet that'd be good for viruses.. Yet, I'm not into those; thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - I think this is the right way to do this (and is how e.g. some database servers work) - suggest you make this comment an answer.

Comment: You can, however, call your process some popular/innocent name, or a name that is similar to a normal Windows process -- so that somebody who wants to terminate your process won't be too easy to find out which.  Incidentally, quite a few **viruses** also work this way.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not looking for a program, thus why would I be asking this, on this site? I'm saying that I want to make my own program..

Comment: ...how about you go back and accept some answers on previous questions. And yes, it sounds like you're trying to write a virus...

Comment: @Stephen: Isn't it possible to attach a program to a process? I think I've seen this in Visual Studios.. Yet, I haven't tried it, or looked into it enough to know what it's about.

Comment: @James Litewski: Yes. Believe it or not I understood. You seem to be confusing security with obscurity. Do you want to secure your sensitive data or just hide it?

Comment: @Mikaveli: I'm not trying to write a virus.. And yes, I was afraid that the question might make it sound like it; but I really am not writing a virus, please believe me.

Comment: @Mikaveli: not a virus, a rootkit. But fortunately not very good at it :)

Comment: @Mitch: I want something to do; and I thought that I could work on this as a small project.

Comment: @Litewski: Why do you need it then? How about locking your computer instead - that way random people can't walk past and stop your process...

Comment: @James - sry: it _is_ helpful. In fact it would be _unhelpful_ if we lull you to sleep by singing siren songs of hidden processes... That's not security. Instead, make these privileged windows services, use ACLs to prohibit STOP/RESTART. Virus scanners/firewall follow that scheme, no hiding, just security

Comment: @sehe: Then tell me to use ACLs from the start.. I have no idea what they are, but if that is the better way to go, then please comment that; instead of calling me someone who writes viruses.

Comment: @Mikaveli: Once again, I'm just doing this as a small project; which means, I don't need to have amazing reasoning for it.. I just want to learn new things.

Comment: @Litewski: People are reluctant to provide a 'how to' for something so easily abused - regardless of your use for it...

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent the termination of your process by using an undocumented API from NTDLL.DLL:

```
typedef VOID ( _stdcall *_RtlSetProcessIsCritical ) (BOOLEAN NewValue,PBOOLEAN OldValue,BOOLEAN IsWinlogon );

void MakeProcessCritical() {
    HMODULE hNtDLL;
    _RtlSetProcessIsCritical RtlSetProcessIsCritical;

    hNtDLL = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll")
    RtlSetProcessIsCritical = (_RtlSetProcessIsCritical)GetProcAddress(hNtDLL, "RtlSetProcessIsCritical");

    if(RtlSetProcessIsCritical != NULL)
         RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0);
}
```

Attempting to end your process will result in an Access denied message.  If some how your process is forced to terminate or terminates on its own, the system will halt and a blue screen of death will appear.  Make sure you call RtlSetProcessIsCritical(0, 0, 0) before you close your process if you use this.

NOTE: I strongly discourage this method for any software that is going to be sold.

Answer (score 3):

> @sehe: Then tell me to use ACLs from the start.. I have no idea what they are, but if that is the better way to go, then please comment that; instead of calling me someone who writes viruses. – James Litewski

@James: If I were about to, I would post answers, not comments. Well, since you asked for it, here is my $0.02:

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/controlling-windows-services-service-accounts.html

> The second one is the service Access Control List (ACL). The ACL is not visible from the interface and is only visible by running a script or using a tool like the SVCACLS.EXE tool from the Windows Resource Kit. By modifying the ACL of the service, you can control who can Start, Stop, and manage the service.

http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-security/60274-gui-available-editing-service-acl.html

By the way, these were the top 2 hit for [`windows service protect ACL`](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=windows+service+protect+ACL&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)